# rails -- track number of user login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tracking

I'd like to track how many times a user logs in to my site which is a Rails app.  Is there any other call like "created_on or updated_on" that can make  a little counter in my model that tracks that kind of info?  I'm using restful-authentication currently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would add `login_count` field to your `User`/`Account` model. Then change this method in `User`/`Account` model:

```
def self.authenticate(login, password)
  return nil if login.blank? || password.blank?
  u = find_by_login(login) # need to get the salt
  u && u.authenticated?(password) ? u.increase_login_count : nil
end
```

and add this method to model:

```
def increase_login_count
  self.login_count += 1
  self.save
  self
end
```

Comment: Is there any reason why this would be preferable to the answer by Lukas?

Comment: I find it better because everything stays in model and not in controller. It will help your database to be consistent.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a column in the user table called login_count or something and then in the SessionsController.create method

```
if user
    user.login_count += 1
    user.save(false)     #update without validations.

    # .... other RestfulAuthentication generated code ....
```